# Removing duplicate dates and merging values in Pandas Dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I am having below data in pandas dataframe. Some date vales are repeating(2010-07-31,2010-10-31). Need to remove repeated dates and merge the values between two rows.

I have used the solution from the following question. But using below code sets Date column as Index. I don't want date column to be set as Index. 
[Need help in removing duplicate dates and merging values of two rows in Pandas Dataframe (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775668/need-help-in-removing-duplicate-dates-and-merging-values-of-two-rows-in-pandas-d)

Code:

```
  df = df.groupby(['Date']).sum()
```

Dataframe `df`:

```
 Index     Date                A       B           C       D
  1     2010-06-30 0:00:00  47.1    29.34       0.036   100.8   
  2     2010-07-31 0:00:00  47.1    29.34               
  3     2010-07-31 0:00:00                      -4.644  100.2   
  4     2010-08-31 0:00:00  47.1    29.34       -1.481  100.4   
  5     2010-09-30 0:00:00  29.3    14.15        3.865  101.6   
  6     2010-10-31 0:00:00  29.3    14.15               
  7     2010-10-31 0:00:00                       0.517  102.6
```

Expected output:

```
 Index     Date              A       B           C       D
  1   2010-06-30 0:00:00   47.1    29.34       0.036   100.8   
  2   2010-07-31 0:00:00   47.1    29.34       -4.644  100.2           
  4   2010-08-31 0:00:00   47.1    29.34       -1.481  100.4   
  5   2010-09-30 0:00:00   29.3    14.15        3.865  101.6   
  6   2010-10-31 0:00:00   29.3    14.15        0.517  102.6
```

Comment: Try this: `df.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: It works fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Reese do not include answer in the comment , you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Reese mentioned -

`df.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False).sum()` will not set date column as Index